# Unit Tests are working fine locally, when executed on build server getting System.IO.FileNotFoundException on local reference

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, jenkins

This is a .Net 4.5 MVC project. The tests execute correctly within Visual Studio. The tests execute correctly on my local environment with Jenkins installed.

But, when I deploy to the corporate build server I get:

Failed   RetailResolutionIsMissingWhenClosingARetailWorkItem
Error Message:
   Unable to create instance of class RetailControllerTest. Error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CCSSWorkflow, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  D:\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\QTAgent32.exe
--- A detailed error log follows.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = CCSSWorkflow, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///E:/ContractsAndPricing/NET/PRD-DEV/workspace/CombinedWorkflow/06202016_CombinedWorkflow_1.7/TestResults/SA-IBM.BFAdmin_WDOH0019APBLD12 2016-07-19 09_24_17/Out
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL

## Calling assembly : CCSSWorkflow.Tests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\QTAgent32.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.
.
Stack Trace:
    at RetailControllerTest..ctor()

for every test.

FYI, the dll that it is complaining about is also part of the solution as a separate project. Everything builds fine. I have it referenced as a project, and I have Copy Local set to true.

Thank you

Comment: Why reference an output (the .dll) directly when the project exists in your solution?

Comment: Just a thought - you might have added the reference to the CCSSWorkflow class in a way that your machine can access it where your build server cannot. E.G. referencing a mapped drive that your build server can't access. Perhaps if you include that DLL in a folder of your project and reference it there you can get around the build server issue. If you need to always compile on the latest version of CCSSWorkflow, it would be best to determine where on the build server the project containing it is storing its DLLs (usually in a release package) and point to that instead.

Comment: Igor, Not sure what you are asking. I am not referencing the dll, I am referencing the project within my solution.